# javascript - how to retireve bytes of file read using readAsArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, filereader, dataview

I am reading a file using FileReader's readAsArrayBuffer. once the file is read, i want to cache its content so that i can submit to the server when the user saves whatever they are doing.

here's my code

```
getFileBuffer: function(file) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred(),reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
   deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
  };
  reader.onerror = function(e) {
   deferred.reject(e.target.error);
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    return deferred;
  };
}
```

and then

```
_.each(evt.target.files, function(file) {
   $this.getFileBuffer(file).done(function(cont) {
     attachment[f.FileName]=cont;
    });
});
```

how do i retrieve this binary content later? when i access the cached object, i get an ArrayBuffer object with a single byteLength property. I am reading this into a DataView but i don't know how to get the actual bytes from this DataView to store them.

Comment: You can convert ArrayBuffer to Blob when send with XHR. There is MDN article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#Sending_binary_data . But it is better not to convert files without the need, as it consumes memory on your browser.

Comment: yeah i used that and it worked on chrome and firefox but not on IE.
 

    `//file content is the ArrayBuffer`
    `var b = new Blob([file.content], {'type': 'application/pdf'});`
    `window.location.href =  window.URL.createObjectURL(b);`

 IE does not open the blob. it shows a window that gets stuck at about:blob